# How to exclude some files from the loop in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

```
#! /bin/sh
for file in $Files/*.txt; do
    chmod 777 $file
done
```

It will give permission `777` to all `.txt` files but I've 7 other `.txt` file for which I don't want to give 777 permission. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, you need some *attribute* to be different on them in order to differentiate between the ones which require either set of permissions. We can not know that you have to explain this in your question.

Comment: I've total 50 .txt files in $FILE directory. now i want to give permission 777 to all files except these 7 .txt files:
school.txt
college.txt
abra.txt
cab.txt
jamla.txt
kalut.txt
aura.txt

Comment: Got it. Please see my answer

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a conditional check as below. As there's no clear attribute differentiating the files you want to exclude, you'd need to specifically check for each name :

```
for file in $Files/*.txt
do 
    if [ "$file" = abra.txt -o "$file" = aura.txt -o "$file" = cab.txt -o "$file" = college.txt -o "$file" = jamla.txt -o "$file" = kalut.txt -o "$file" = school.txt  ]
    then 
       continue 
    fi 
    chmod 777 "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

A POSIX sh solution.

```
#! /bin/sh

for file in $Files/*.txt; do
   case $file in
    foo.txt|bar.txt|more.txt) continue;;   ##: Skip files that matched.
    *) chmod 777 "$file";;                 ##: Change permission to the rest.
   esac                
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
find . ! -iregex '.*/school\.txt\|.*/college.txt\|.*/abra\.txt\|.*/cab\.txt\|.*/jamla\.txt\|.*/kalut\.txt\|.*/aura\.txt' -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

And it will do. Let me know if it helps!